# get a list of files with N commits from git

Tags: bash, git, git-filter-repo

I am trying to get a list of files in a git repository that have only a single commit. So from the subject `N` would be `1`.

I have a bash script which can perform the job. However, I would like to do this with just `git` commands. I have access to `git filter-repo` and I can't find a way in that [documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) either.

This is part of an `svn` to `git` migration and it would be nice to get this information without the `find` since the first repository created does not have files until it is `clone`'d once.

The bash script that works is:

```bash
export OFS=$IFS; export IFS=$'\n'; total=0; for i in $(find . -type f -not -path "./.git/*"); do sum=`git log --graph --oneline --reflog --all --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h%d (%an, %ar)' $I | wc -l ; if [[ $sum -gt 0 ]]; then let "total++"; echo $i" "$sum; fi; done; echo "total files = $total"
```

The bash one-liner can be shortened but that isn't what I'm trying to figure out. I'm attempting to find a way to get similar information with `git`. Namely, I would like a programmatic `git` solution to get the list of files with `N` commits. In my use `N` is 1.

Comment: Only the current files? Or even deleted files?

Comment: @Schwern, I was only after current but deleted doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These build-with-just-one-tool conceits might make fun puzzles, but the fact is Git's one tool in a very capable toolbox.

```
git log --pretty= --name-status | awk -F$'\t' '!seen[$2]++ && $1=="A"'
```

will find all files that haven't been touched since being added.

Comment: I like it, but I might use `git log --pretty= --name-status | awk -F$'\t' '!seen[$2]++ && $1=="A" {print $2}'` for just the filenames.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is a pure Git solution to this exact problem. Git is designed to be used with Unix shell utilities. But we can do it easier.

Assuming you want only information about the current set of files (not those which have been deleted), use [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) to get a list of the current files known to Git (safer than using `find`). Then run each through `git log --oneline`.

```
for f in `git ls-files`; do
  echo "$f: $(git log --oneline $f | wc -l)";
done
```

To get a list of files which only appear in one commit, check when `git log` only returns one line.

```
for f in `git ls-files`; do
  if [ $(git log --oneline $f | wc -l) = "1" ]; then
    echo $f;
  fi;
done
```

You can make this a [Git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) or an actual program by calling it `git-whatever` and putting it in your path.

```
$ cat ~/bin/git-files-with-one-commit 
#!/bin/bash

for f in `git ls-files`; do
  if [ $(git log --oneline $f | wc -l) = "1" ]; then
    echo $f;
  fi;
done

$ chmod +x ~/bin/git-files-with-one-commit 

$ git files-with-one-commit
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the git alias reminder. I will probably make an alias out @jthill's approach.

Comment: @jj2f1 Theirs is likely more efficient as it only requires one traversal of the history.